# How to stop powershell runspace before reCall it

Tags: powershell, runspace

I have a list of items on a powershell GUI, when I clic one, I call the same runspace `$runspace.BeginInvoke()`

But if I click on quickly the first instance is in progress for the second item. I Stop it (`$runspace.stop()` and `$runspace.dispose()`) berore recall my runspace.

but sometimes my GUI fail between `Stop()` and `dispose()`. I can only assume that this method is not good

Comment: What fails? How? Any errors?

Comment: Runspaces doesn't have a `Stop()` method - a you talking about the `PowerShell` class?